# Pygame Midi libasound_module_conf_pulse.so error + unable to open slave

Tags: pygame, alsa, slave, libasound

I was getting this error when I tried to run my pygame.midi code:

```
ALSA lib conf.c:3558:(snd_config_hooks_call) Cannot open shared library libasound_module_conf_pulse.so (/usr/lib/alsa-lib/libasound_module_conf_pulse.so: libasound_module_conf_pulse.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
ALSA lib seq.c:935:(snd_seq_open_noupdate) Unknown SEQ default
```

I found out that the path Python was searching for did not exist. For some reason, `libasound_module_conf_pulse.so` is located in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib`, so I created `alsa-lib` directory in `/usr/lib/` and copied the contents of `usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib` in it.

That fixed the first error. Now, I am encountering another error, which I think is related to the really shady fix I applied above (why I included both of them in the same question). When running `pygame.init()` I get this error:

`ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1089:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave`

I have searched the web and found only one question related but sadly left unanswered. What I understand is that using methods from pygame.midi works but using methods from pygame such as init throws the error.

So, this code works fine:

```
import pygame.midi
import pygame

def print_devices():
    for n in range(pygame.midi.get_count()):
        print (n,pygame.midi.get_device_info(n))

def number_to_note(number):
    notes = ['c', 'c#', 'd', 'd#', 'e', 'f', 'f#', 'g', 'g#', 'a', 'a#', 'b']
    return notes[number%12]

def readInput(input_device):
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while True:
        if input_device.poll():
            event = input_device.read(1)[0]
            data = event[0]
            timestamp = event[1]
            note_number = data[1]
            velocity = data[2]
            if (velocity!=0):
                print (number_to_note(note_number), velocity)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.midi.init()
    my_input = pygame.midi.Input(3)
    readInput(my_input)
    my_output = pygame.midi.Output(2)
    my_output.note_on(90,120)
    my_output.note_off(90, 120)
```

but adding `pygame.init()` throws the slave error.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and Python 3.8 in PyCharm.

Edit: Running the above code directly in Python from the terminal does not give the slave error on `pygame.init()` but will sometimes give a `(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred` error.

Comment: The "Unknown SEQ default" message means that ALSA and/or PulseAudio is not installed correctly, or that the ALSA configuration files have been modified in an inappropriate way.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue using mido and instead of copying the file I made a symbolic link from `/usr/lib64/alsa-lib` to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib`:

`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib /usr/lib64/alsa-lib`

No copy and works like magic. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue using PyGame in Blender, the "hack" above, copying the files to `/usr/lib/alsa-lib` got rid of the error for me and made sounds and PyGame work properly. I only had this issue on Ubuntu, not my Mac. I didn't ever get the "slave" error.

FTR, I am using PyGame to input live MIDI commands from either a keyboard or controller to animate in Blender.